# How to read permission of the Document Library Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, permissions, csom

I have a document from document library which is shared with other users.
I want to read the all the permissions for that particular document using CSOM. 
Please suggest the solution for it.

```
 ClientContext.Load(_list.RootFolder.Files);//List is DocumentLibrary type
    ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
     foreach (SPFile _File in _list.RootFolder.Files)
    {
       //How to get permission for the file.
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code which can be used for retrieving document permissions:

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetURL);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, passWord);

ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
SP.ListCollection listCol = web.Lists;
ctx.Load(listCol);

SP.List list = listCollection.GetByTitle("ListTitle");

SP.CamlQuery camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "";

SP.ListItemCollection listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
ctx.Load(listItemCollection);

//Execute Query 
ctx.ExecuteQuery();


SP.ListItem listItem = listItemCollection.FirstOrDefault(t => t.DisplayName == "WordFileName");

ctx.Load(listItem,
    li => li.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,
    li => li.RoleAssignments.Include(
        p => p.Member,
        p => p.RoleDefinitionBindings.Include(
            s => s.Name)));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

if (listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
    //Get all the RoleAssignments for this document
    foreach (RoleAssignment rAssignment in listItem.RoleAssignments)
    {
        //A single RA can have multiple bindings
        foreach (RoleDefinition rDef in rAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Role assigned to the member, ", rAssignment.Member.LoginName, " is ", rDef.Name));
        }
    }
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("The current ListItem has no unique roles assigned to it.");
```

Reference - https://piyushksingh.com/2014/08/01/get-a-list-of-all-the-shared-users-for-a-listitemdocument-of-sharepoint-list-using-client-object-model-c/